# Save HTML drag 'n drop without database

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Like the title says: Is it possible to save any changes that are done on a website with HTML5 drag and drop without saving it in a database? What I want to do is a list of names that should be able to be moved between different divs on the site. I want to do it as smooth and easy as possible.

/Håkan

Comment: If you talk about a single user you may use cookies. Elsewhere you need database so that the changes be visible for other visitors.

Comment: ok. thanks. I was hoping there were another way to save it for others...

Comment: Don't forget localStorage and sessionStorage.  Again, a per-user solution.  Saving it for others will need a db.

Comment: A database might be the most simple option, though you could write it into a file. Be sure to clear your user entered values from any tags, etc.

Comment: wouldn't I need php to write it into a db?

Comment: php or any other server language

Comment: great. Looks like I have some research to do now...